# Infinite lock problem with a bike lock finding the minimum turns needed

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, discrete-optimization

For example there is a bike lock that rotates the numbers $0$-$9$,on six separate dials, and if multiple dials are adjacent they can be rotated in the same direction for the same number of rotations (i.e., three adjacent dials all moving $2$ places anti-clockwise).

What is the minimum number of rotations needed to get the bike lock to the specific combination to unlock from any possible starting position. So the minimum maximum number of rotations given a specific number of dials and numbers the dials. Also consider that we can assume we want 000000, as the unlock position as it will be the same results no matter what the end position is for the number of turns.

I know how you could find it if there was no adjacent turns allowed, but this complicates the problem. As adjacent turns have to be accounted for.

A general solution is the rounded up value of half the number of dials times half the number of numbers on the dials. However I have not proved this for many case scenarios. And it may be a overestimate with larger values.

Comment: What’s infinite here?

Comment: So $n$ adjacent dials can be turned $n$ times? Or any number of times?

Comment: The number of dials is n1 and the numbers the dials go up to is n2, sorry not making it clear, I just gave the 6 dials and 0-9 as an example as you could find this actual result in numbers but a general solution for two different n values up to infinity is what I want.

Comment: In the worst case, all the dials start on the same number but need to be set to different numbers, so you need a number of rotations equal to the number of dials.

Comment: that Won’t work imagine just two dials with 0-9 they both start on 00 but both need to be on 44 that requires 4 turns. I understand the logic but it simply won’t work.

Comment: @joriki the number of dials is n1 and number of numbers n2, these are from 1 to infinity. I want a general solution for any values of n1 and n2, that’s more accurate than mine or see if mine is the most accurate. Thanks very much.